# How to represent a data structure like this in python pandas?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Somehow I can't figure out what would be the best/most convenient representation of my data in python pandas.

In principle the data is structured like this:

```
            |        Group1       |  |        Group2       | ...
   x  y  z    prop1  prop2  prop3      prop1  prop2  prop3
0  o  o  o      o      o      o          o      o      o
1  o  o  o      o      o      o          o      o      o
2  o  o  o      o      o      o          o      o      o
.
.
.
```

So to say, I have a *fixed* number of rows indexed by 0, 1, 2, ... Each row has *fixed* (x,y,z) coordinates and a *fixed* number of data groups (here: Group1, Group2, ...) which themselves have a *fixed* number of properties. The "o"s denote data values. What I would want is a DataFrame where I could write

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Dataframe( "the_unknown_code" )
df['x'] # giving the "x"-column
df['Group1']['prop1'] # giving the "prop1"-column of "Group1"
```

This would be easy from my point of view, if DataFrame-columns could be DataFrames again, which does not seem to be possible. I tried to get along with Panel and Multiindex, but it seemed that I would have duplicate data or too complex indexing. I would highly appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(27).reshape(3,9) , 
columns = [
     ['x' , 'y' , 'z' , 'Group1' , 'Group1' , 'Group1' , 'Group2' , 'Group2' , 'Group2'] , 
     [ 'x' , 'y' , 'z' , 'prop1' , 'prop2' , 'prop3' , 'prop1' , 'prop2' , 'prop3']
          ]
)

df['Group1']['prop1']

# 0     3
# 1    12
# 2    21
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is working quite well but not completely as expected. `df['Group1']['prop1'].values.shape` gives me `(3, )`, but `df['x'].values.shape` gives `(3, 1)`. This is because to actually access the x-row vector I would need to write `df['x']['x']`, which is quite inconvenient, right?

Comment: it may be inconvenient but it does the job , I'm not sure if this is doable in panda or not , because you want a mix of multi-index column and normal columns